# using DOS, Tee32 3.2 by Brian Friesen, capture return code

Tags: shell, ant, dos, tee

I am using a pipe to TEE a call to apache ant

```
SET ERRORLEVEL=
call C:\ant\bin\ant.bat %* |TEE build-logs\build-log-%yyyy%%mm%%dd%.%hh%%nn%%ss%.txt
echo ERRORLEVEL %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Which gives me a consistent `ERRORLEVEL 4264624` when I use a test task with or without `<fail/>` in it.

In other words I am not getting the status of ant.bat, but something else.

This is DOS not BASH, so I don't have access to

```
echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
```

Is there a direct solution to this, if not my goals are to log ant output as shown, and to capture the return code.

Comment: You might have more success with powershell, instead of DOS.

Answer (score 0):

You could direct ant output to file using the `-logger` [command line option](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html).

```
ant -l <logfile>
```

But this would not also write to stdout, which I guess TEE is doing for you.

To get output to file and stdout you should be able to use a [Log4jListener](http://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html#Log4jListener) with log4j configuration to write to console and file.